# Append content to WKWebView in iOS 10

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I am looking to periodically continuing appending HTML to my WKWebView. Think of a chat room. Every time a line of chat comes in, I add an additional line of content to the view. I found the following method:

```
func loadHTMLString(_ string: String, 
            baseURL: URL?) -> WKNavigation?
```

This seems to be a one time load, however. I don't want to overwrite the content I have in my WKWebView. Instead I want to continue appending data to it as it becomes available.

What's the best way of going about that?

Comment: @matt typos, thanks. Meant WKWebView

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way is to call [`evaluateJavaScript`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/webkit/wkwebview/1415017-evaluatejavascript). This allows you to modify the DOM in real time.